# Knockoutjs component not able to use js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I am trying to create a component that is basically a search bar.  These search bars in the backend will 'and' together all the terms that are searched for.

So I have created the component and I am able to see it, my css is working fine, but for some reason it will not run my js function that I am trying to use to animate the label.  This is of course only one of the issues.  I am also already noticing that because I connect the label to the search bar with an id, and id's can only be used once, it is making it so I can't search on the second or nth bar without clicking on a spot without the label.

Any ideas how I am work around these issues with a component?

Here is my component code:

```
 ko.components.register('andBlock', {
  template:
      '<div class="andDisplay"> \
        <div class="initalAndOutput"> \
          <p class="orTermHeader" data-bind=""></p> \
          <span class="orTermList" data-bind=""></span> \
        </div> \
        <div class="searchForm andSearchForm" action=""> \
          <div class="andSearchBar"> \
            <label for="twoSearch">Add search term</label> \
            <input id="twoSearch" class="andSearch searching autocomplete" name="search" type="text" data-bind="" /> \
            <span class="searchIcon"><a class="mdi mdi-magnify mdi-18px" href="#"></a> \
          </div> \
        </div> \
      </div>'
});
```

Here is the jquery function I am trying to run:

```
$(function() {
  $('.andSearch').keyup(function() {
      $('.andSearchBar').addClass('typing');
      if($(this).val().length === 0) {
          $('.andSearchBar').removeClass('typing');
      }
  });
});
```

This is all I am doing to populate the component in the HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: andsCollection">
   <div data-bind="component: 'andBlock'"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `andBlock` component is dynamically created so the events that you registered on document load did not hit the component which you created in the later time.

So you should use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It will register events to descendant elements that will be created at later time.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("keyup", '.andSearch', function() {
      $(this).closest('.andSearchBar').addClass('typing');
      if($(this).val().length === 0) {
          $('.andSearchBar').removeClass('typing');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't know why I totally over looked that.  Thank you!  Any idea how I can deal with the id issue within the knockoutjs components?

Comment: Do you mean redundant id's? If it is then you can append the id with an incremented id from `andsCollection` item (e.g. `data-bind="attr: {id: 'twoSearch' + $data.id()}"`), or you can scrape the idea of id and just use classes.